# Which device gets the helper-address?

Tags: cisco, dhcp

Brand new to  networking and trying different scenarios.

PC2 can successfully send packets to PC1 and the DHCP server **if a static address is assigned**. However, PC2 will not obtain a DHCP address from the server.

I'm assuming at this point, a helper address is required, but **I'm not sure which switch or router that should be defined on**

Note: All devices are on Vlan 1 - DHCP is configured correctly for 64 subnet

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You configure the helper aka DHCP relay with the address of the DHCP server. The helper needs to be share a broadcast domain with the DHCP client.

In your diagram, you need to configure the helper on Router B / Gig0/0/0 and point it at 192.168.1.5. Obviously, the DHCP server needs to have a configured scope for 10.25.64.0/24.

Comment: It appears that the helper-address had to be entered AFTER the static routes were assigned. I'm not sure why, but it seemed to have worked.

Comment: I need proper routing between the DHCP relay and the server, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Router B. Int G0/0/0.  This will forward the DHCP traffic.

Comment: Helper address will be the address of your DHCP server.

Comment: To provide a little more info.  Routers are designed to block broadcast traffic.  DHCP Requests are broadcast traffic.  So you need to add the helper address to forward that traffic.

Comment: Routers don't "block broadcast traffic"; they don't *forward* broadcast traffic, because it's supposed to be link-local. The helper-address tells the router to enable it's DHCP Relay Agent, and what DHCP server to use.